# Existe um "sudo" para Windows?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd

Normalmente é fácil abrir um programa/script `.bat` com elevação usando a opção *"Executar como Administrador"* do botão direito.

Mas e se eu quiser rodar algo com elevação a partir do `cmd`, uma espécie de `sudo`, tem como?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A ferramenta [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc771525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) do Windows é equivalente ao [`sudo`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_sudo.htm) do *Unix/Linux*. A sua sintaxe é:

```
runas [/profile | /noprofile] [/env] [/netonly | /savecred] [/showtrustlevels] [/trustlevel] /user:<UserName> "<PathToProgramFile>"
```

### Exemplos

O comando abaixo executa o Prompt de Comando como administrador(*root*).

```
runas /user:Administrator cmd
```

No *Unix/Linux* equivale simplesmente a:

```
sudo /bin/sh
```

Ou através do comando abaixo:

```
su -
```

**Nota**: Se você não utiliza o Bash pode-se saber o shell que você usa a partir do comando `which sh`.

Se necessitar carregar o perfil do usuário pode-se fazer:

```
runas /profile /env /user:<Usuario> "notepad"
```

No *Unix/Linux* pode equivaler a:

```
sudo -u <Usuario> -i
```

Em contrapartida, se você não quer carregar o perfil do usuário pode-se usar:

```
runas /noprofile /user:<Usuario> "notepad"
```

Com o `sudo` poderíamos utilizar:

```
sudo -u root vi /etc/sudoers
```

Há também ferramentas externas que podem fazer a elevação, por exemplo o [**Sudo for Windows**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/).

Caso você utilize o [**ConEmu**](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/)(*é uma ótima alternativa ao Prompt de Comando do Windows*) pode-se utilizar o comando [`csudo`](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/csudo) para executar uma ação com privilégios.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outras alternativas podem ser vistas [**aqui**](http://pplware.sapo.pt/truques-dicas/que-alternativas-existem-no-windows-ao-sudo-do-linux/).

Poderíamos criar um arquivo *batch* para realizar essa tarefa através do `runas`:

```bat
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "ARG=%*"

if !ARG! == "" (
  echo.Sem argumentos validos
  goto :NOARGS 
) ELSE (
  goto :EXECRUNAS
  exit /b 0
)

:NOARGS
  echo.Modo de uso:  %~n0  -u [usuario] [comando1, comando2, comandoN]
  exit /b 0

:EXECRUNAS:
if "%1" == "-u" (
  set USER=%2
  SHIFT
) ELSE (
  echo.Especifique o usuario & echo.
  goto :NOARGS
)

SHIFT
set "skip=2"

for %%I IN (!ARG!) DO IF !skip! LEQ 0 ( 
  set args=!args! %%I
) ELSE set /a skip-= 1 


for %%i IN (!args!) do (
  runas /env /user:!USER! "cmd /k \"%%i\"" 
)

echo.Tarefa Finalizada & echo.
exit /b 0
```

Basta salvar o arquivo com um nome de sua preferência, com a extensão `.bat` e chamá-lo através do *prompt* assim:

```
bat_sudo  -u [usuario] [comando1, comando2, comandoN]
```

Por exemplo:

```
bat_sudo -u Administrator gpedit.msc mmc regedit
```

Lembrando que o *script* separa os comandos através de espaços, portanto se passar um comando como `at 1` o *script* interpretará como sendo dois comandos destintos.

Answer (score 18):

Por padrão o usuário local (Dominio = .) elevado no windows em ingles é Administrator.

Desta forma:

> runas /user:.\Administrator "caminho\Programa.exe"

Answer (score 13):

Crie um arquivo `sudo.bat` e cole nele o seguinte conteúdo:

```
@echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") > %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo args = Right("%*", (Len("%*") - Len("%1"))) >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo objShell.ShellExecute "%1", args, "", "runas" >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@cscript %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
```

Se quiser você pode colocá-lo na pasta `C:\Windows` ou outra pasta que esteja na variável PATH de ambiente, para que o Windows o reconheça automaticamente.

Utilização: `sudo <executável>` (exemplo: `sudo notepad`), e ele vai abrir a janela do [UAC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) pra você.

Answer (score 1):

Sabemos que o "**runas**" não consegue fazer a elevação do privilégio para um comando específico na linha de comando. O que ele faz é executar um comando com outro usuário, no caso, podendo ser o usuário Administrador.

Acontece que no cenário, onde o usuário quer apenas elevar seu nível de processo para que seja equivalente ao "**Executar como Administrador**", que existe no menu de contexto de cada arquivo executável, sem mudar o usuário.

No caso de estar usando o Windows dentro de uma empresa, e embora meu usuário esteja no grupo de Administradores locais, eu não tenho a senha do usuário "**Administrador**", o uso do "**runas**" não resolve. Então deixa de ser equivalente ao "sudo".

Outra alternativa além do "**Sudo for Windows**" é usar o [Elevate](http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/). Trata-se de um pequeno utilitário, que faz exatamente o que o "sudo command" faz.

Assim, as seguintes linhas sejam equivalentes:

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts

elevate notepad.exe c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    runas /user:administrador "time 12"
```

Comment: Parece a mesma resposta dos demais usuários, mas não tem explicação, poderia dizer o que a sua resposta tem de diferente?